# React Hook Form useFieldArray removes data after adding the second time on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, next.js13

In my component, have a input for adding sku and a button to fetch product based on the respective sku from API. On successful fetch, the product gets added to a dynamic table.

What I am trying to implement here is, I can fetch product by sku multiple times, and after each call, the particular fetched product will be added to the dynamic table.

The input and table is part of a form managed using React Hook Form. To manage the table dynamically, I am using `useFieldArray` from react hook form.

Here is my code:

**Input:**

```
<SkuInput register={register} errors={errors} handleClick={getProduct} />
```

**Fetching product by SKU:**

```
const getProduct = async () => {
    const sku = getValues("searchedSKU");
    const product = await getProductBySKU( sku);
    if (product) {
      prepend(product);
    }
  };
```

**react-hook-form config:**

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormValues>({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(purchaseValidationSchema),
  });
  const { prepend } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "tableName",
  });
```

**sending data to the table component:**

```
 <Controller
          name="tableName"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <DataTable
              data={field.value}
              onChange={field.onChange}
              onDelete={onDelete}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Now all of these above works for the first call to the product. When I add a SKU and fetch product the second time, the product is not added to the table.

So to debug this, I console logged `watch("tableName")`, and realised that the second time, product gets added to the array defined in `useFieldArray`, but component re-renders again and removes it from the `useFieldArray`.

I spent good amount of time looking for a cause of re-render and why it removes the data from useFieldArray, but got no clue. I am not using any hook that can re-render the component.

I am not sure what am I missing. This is nextJS 13 and react-hook-form 7.45.

Comment: So I can see both object in fieldArray in main form context. So somehow the updated state is not being passed to table controller.